# How to change text location?

Tags: css

I an working on my tutorial project:

I have this code:

```js
// Code goes here
angular.module('switchdemo', []).controller('DemoController', function($scope){
  
  $scope.init = function(){
    $scope.status = true;
  }
  

    $scope.changeStatus = function(){
    $scope.status = !$scope.status;
  }
})
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

.active, .inactive {font-size:40px;cursor:pointer;}
.active, .inactive {font-size:40px;cursor:pointer;}
i.active { color: #5cb85c}
i.inactive {color: #d9534f}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.6" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.6/angular.js"></script>
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="switchdemo">

  <div ng-controller="DemoController" ng-init="init()">
    <div class="well">

      <i class="fa fa-toggle-on active" ng-if="status == true" ng-click="changeStatus();"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-toggle-on fa-rotate-180 inactive" ng-if="status == false" ng-click="changeStatus();"></i>
 <h5>dummy! </h5>
    </div>
    <pre>{{ status }}</pre>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

How can I make dummy! word to be on the same line with ON/OFF switch from the right.

Like this:

[image]

Comment: you want the 'dummy' word or status on the right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

H5 is a block element by default, which means it will be on a new line. Use span or assign `display: inline` or `display: inline-block` to your H5 tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `float` property set to left as follows:

```
<div class="well">
    <div>
      <i class="fa fa-toggle-on active" ng-if="status == true" ng-click="changeStatus();"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-toggle-on fa-rotate-180 inactive" ng-if="status == false" ng-click="changeStatus();"></i>
   </div>
 <h5 class="align-left">dummy! </h5>
```

CSS:

```
.align-left {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `display: inline-block` to `<h5>`, because `<h5>` acts like a block element

```js
// Code goes here
angular.module('switchdemo', []).controller('DemoController', function($scope){
  
  $scope.init = function(){
    $scope.status = true;
  }
  

    $scope.changeStatus = function(){
    $scope.status = !$scope.status;
  }
})
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

h5{ display: inline-block;}
.active, .inactive {font-size:40px;cursor:pointer;}
.active, .inactive {font-size:40px;cursor:pointer;}
i.active { color: #5cb85c}
i.inactive {color: #d9534f}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.6" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.6/angular.js"></script>
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="switchdemo">

  <div ng-controller="DemoController" ng-init="init()">
    <div class="well">

      <i class="fa fa-toggle-on active" ng-if="status == true" ng-click="changeStatus();"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-toggle-on fa-rotate-180 inactive" ng-if="status == false" ng-click="changeStatus();"></i>
 <h5>dummy! </h5>
    </div>
    <pre>{{ status }}</pre>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ,thanks for the answer but what if I use <h5> in another places and I don't want it to be acted like a block element?

Comment: You can create a class to do this and assign that class to your H5 tag.